# A not clear chain of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Look at the following excerpt from the book "J.Talbot, D.Welsh - Complexity and Cryptography":

---

[image]

---

First of all I don't understand the chain of inequalities. Moreover if in the last term $(t+1){\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^t$ we put $t=8p(n)$ where $p(n):\mathbb N\longrightarrow\mathbb N$ is a polynomial  with $p(n)\ge 1$, I can't prove that $$(8p(n)+1){\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{8p(n)}\le\frac{1}{2^{p(n)}}$$
as it is claimed in the highlighted phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is because there are $t+1$ terms in the sum, and the last one is the biggest.  The next uses the fact that $\binom{n}{k}$, the numbers of subsets of $n$ with size $k$, is less than $2^n$, the number of subsets of $n$.

Now $(3/4)^8$ is less than $1/8$.  This means that the LHS is less than $(1/2)^{p(n)}$ times $(8p(n)+1)(1/4)^{p(n)}$.  We now look at $(8p(n)+1)(1/4)^{p(n)}$ and notice that it is less than 1 if $p(n)\geq 3$.  We can also check the inequality directly for $p(n)=2$.  It does not hold for $p(n)=1$.

Comment: Many thanks but I think that also for $p(n)=2$ the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: I think the $p(n)=2$ case holds.  My sloppy approximation that $(3/4)^{8}$ is less than $1/8$ is not quite good enough, but $(17)(3/4)^{16}$ is about $.17$.